# How to count the Quantity of formulae in a Google Sheets Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to count the number of formulae in a complex Google sheets doc (multi tabbed)

I have reworked an old template using functions like ARRAYFORMULA and so on and i would really like to determine the reduction in complexity - number of formulae being one proxy for this. There were many thousands of row-by-row, column-by-column copy/paste calcs originally.

Comment: About `count the number of formulae`, you want to retrieve the number of cells including the formulas on all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: You should calculate "time" to load as the criteria for performance rather than the number of formulas.

Comment: @TheMaster you are right. The performance on the old sheet was poor and slow to load. Any consistent ways to achieve this? I have also noticed watching TaskManager that the older sheet with all the version baggage takes loads of memory and when you take a new copy and presumably it drops a lot of baggage, it can be dramatically less = more performant, faster loading etc.

Comment: @Aitch I can't think of a programmatic way to do this. You can use `onOpen()` to log the time it takes the script to finally start( usually scripts start after all formulas has loaded). But you must log the actual open time on your own. Time to load = script time-manually logged time.   Another possibility that comes to mind is `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. The time taken for this call using `console.time()` "may" reflect performance(as it kind of syncs formula to server), but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can get all formulae in all cells in all Sheets, and add one to a counter if the cell starts with the `=` character.*

#### Code:

```js
function getAllFormulae() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var count = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    var currSheetValues = ss[i].getDataRange().getFormulas();
    for (var j = 0; j < currSheetValues.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < currSheetValues[j].length; k++) {
        if (currSheetValues[j][k].startsWith("=") == 1) {
          count++
        }
      }
    }
  }  
  return count;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to retrieve the number of cells including the formulas on all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script. So how about this sample script?

I thought that when various approaches are proposed, they might be useful for users. So I would like to propose the following 2 sample scripts.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, all sheets are retrieved from the active Spreadsheet, and the number of cells including formulas are retrieved from each sheet. In order to count the number of elements, the 2 dimensional array is flatten.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const res = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()
    .reduce((n, s) => n += s.getDataRange().getFormulas().flat().filter(String).length, 0);
  console.log(res)
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the formulas are retrieved using TextFinder. In this case, all formulas can be retrieved from all sheets in the active Spreadsheet without using the loop process. The detail process for searching is run at the internal server of Google side. In my environment, it is found that the process cost of this pattern was lower than that of pattern 1. Under the same condition, the cost of pattern 2 was about 1/5 of the cost of pattern 1.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const res = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .createTextFinder("^\\=")
    .matchFormulaText(true)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .findAll().length;
  console.log(res)
}
```

### Note:

- Both patterns return the same result.
- Please run the script with enabling V8.

### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Pattern 2 is a very elegant solution which worked on my "new" sheet but did not work on the "old" sheet, I am trying to determine why and will report back.

Comment: @Aitch Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, although I cannot replicate it, I think that the answers of various patterns for your question will be useful for a lot of users. Thank you for your good question.

Comment: I *think* it is something to do with protected or hidden sheets. I still haven't got to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Aitch Thank you for replying. It seems that the pattern 2 is not affected to the protect and hide sheet. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getformulas) to get all formulas and count all elements that are not empty:

```
const getTotalFormulasCount = () =>
  console.log(getNumFormulas_(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()));

/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet[]|string[][]|string[]} arr Array of sheets or 1D or 2D array of formulas
 * @returns {number} count of formulas present in arr
 */
const getNumFormulas_ = arr =>
  arr.reduce(
    (count, el) =>
      count +
      (Array.isArray(el) //if el is array, recurse
        ? getNumFormulas_(el)
        : el.getRange //if el is sheet, recurse over it's formulas
        ? getNumFormulas_(el.getDataRange().getFormulas())
        : Number(el !== '')),
    0
  );
```